# Silence ActiveRecord / MySQL log output in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a way to silence/disable mysql output in the development.log?

For example this stuff:

```
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `billing_infos` (`billing_method`, `city`, `company_id`, `country`, `created_at`, `email`, `fax_number`, `phone_number`, `postal_code`, `province`, `street`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, 'Montreal', NULL, 'Canada', '2011-10-26 20:53:45', NULL, NULL, '(123) 456 7890', 'H1H1H1', 'QC', '1111 Temp', '2011-10-26 20:53:45')
 (0.3ms)  COMMIT
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 (0.1ms)  COMMIT
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `sectors` WHERE (`sectors`.`name` = BINARY 'General 25' AND `sectors`.`id` != 1) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to suppress almost all log output, @Shirjeel's approach will work, though I find it a bit heavy handed.

If you prefer to suppress output for a single ActiveRecord class, and only within a specific block, you can use `silence`:

```
BillingInfo.silence do
  BillingInfo.create(:city => "Montreal")
  BillingInfo.create(:city => "Ottawa")
  ... etc
end
```

If you want to suppress output for *all* ActiveRecord subclasses, you can do

```
ActiveRecord::Base.silence do
  ... manipulate database quietly here...
end
```

I use this when I'm importing a large block of records or generating large test cases.

Comment: Turns out this is deprecated in Rails 4.0 due to thread safety issues. There's no alternative that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Add following line to your config/environments/development.rb file

`config.log_level = :info`